# Allowing non-root users permission to tty1 for Gnome X-server on Arch

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, tty, x-server

I have Arch installed on my Lenovo T440p, and I'm trying to get the Gnome desktop environment to work.

I have edited /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config to add: 
 allowed_users=anybody

I made my user and added it to wheel group. When I am logged on as the user and type startx, X-server crashes with error:

/dev/tty1: Permission denied

Comment: Can you say more about what you did since the Arch wiki entries for [GDM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM) and [GDE](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME) do not mention editing Xwrapper.config. What command do you run (and as what user) that causes the crash.

Comment: First, check that your really have Xwrapper and it has suid bit. Is your ``X`` or ``Xorg`` points to wrapper? Second, it is much better use display manager instead of running X directly.

Comment: Arch changes faster than its documentation. Can you explain where/how to find the Xwrapper file that needs the suid bit set? How do I find out if X or Xorg points to the wrapper?

Comment: I like to run `startx` before setting up a display manager just because then I have less parts involved if my system fails to boot to a graphical login screen. In any case, I've been using Arch for more than 5 years, and installed a dozen or so systems during that time, I've *never* had to modify anything in `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config` in order to run `startx` as a non-root user. Reading the manpage the default (`allowed_users=console`) should be enough, do you also set `needs_root_rights`?

Comment: '$ cat /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config'  'allowed_users=console'  'needs_root_rights=no'  I think it might have something to do with the recent changes in xorg-server respository  [https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/69r15f/xorgserverutils_removed/]  Maybe I have the wrong hardware settings...?

Comment: Are you a member of the `video` group?

Comment: You can get the PID of the shell in which you are going to run `startx` with `echo $$`. Then you can attach `strace` from a root shell to it and log the syscalls: `strace -o startx.strace -f -p 1234` That should show you which process fails with which access exactly. That may help you understand the problem.